# line of red zeros in file /var/log/syslog

Tags: crash, ext4, syslog

Im currently fighting a nasty SSD bug [Ubuntu freezes and shows errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207289/ubuntu-freezes-and-shows-errors), a user advised me to grab hold of the `/var/log/syslog` file to look out for any culprit files. Now I actually succeeded in retriving the file. I noticed nothing extraordinary, but a red line of zeros in one of the lines. Does this have any special meaning?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [^@^@ character in syslog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356981/character-in-syslog); note: those are NUL charactrs BTW

Comment: @αғsнιη yes! Thank you!